# div has no height

Tags: html, css

I have 3 divs with the class stackContainer:

```
.stackContainer {
    position: relative;
}
```

In that there are a lot of divs, i want those on top of each other, this works:

```
.stackItem {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Only the 3 stackContainers shouldn't be on top of each other.
I think it's just a minor css thing.

http://jsfiddle.net/vPtYD/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want to achieve?
http://jsfiddle.net/Vfqsr/

Comment: cool, almost, now you have 1 stack, i want 3 stacks, for each container 1 stack. And then the width and height of the container must be based on the items it holds.

Comment: Here: http://jsfiddle.net/Vfqsr/1/ . I think this should do the trick. Change `5` from `$margin = 5` to modify the distance between stackItems.

Comment: one more, http://jsfiddle.net/Vfqsr/6/ is it easy to prevent them going out the screen? And why are they under each other and not next to each other?

Answer (score 1):

If everything in the `stackContainer` divs is positioned absolutely, those divs don't know how high they should be, becaause elements with `position:absolute` are taken out of the normal text flow.

So your best bet is to figure out what the largest content of each div is, and set the `height` properties of the stackContainers to those values explicitly.

Or, give them at least one child element that is not positioned absolutely.

Comment: @clankill3r Ehm... look at the source?

Comment: `look at the source` exactly, it's not Flash.

Comment: @Bdesign They do use Flash, but to be honest, I'm not sure what for exactly. When loading, you do see the Flash "wait cursor" icon for a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Give the `stackContainer` width and height as well:

```
.stackContainer {
    position: relative;
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
}
```

Comment: JavaScript. View the page source and you'll see very extensive usage of jQuery. It's not pure CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can put height on .stackContainer

```
.stackContainer {
    height:200px;
}

.stackItem {
    position:absolute;
}
```